Lower bounds on Sample Complexity for an Online Game Theory Problem
I'm trying to find papers that prove lower bounds on sample complexity for game theory problems. One approach I know that you can use is show that if you can approximate the optimal solution to the game theory problem within some error of $\epsilon$, then you can learn a distribution or distinguish between two distributions within an error of $\epsilon$.
What are examples of papers that specifically use this approach, or prove sample complexity lower bounds for a specific problem in general?
